# How to make first pair of fields required, and rest not required

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Trying to build a function where AT LEAST one pair of the field pair **s_AAA/s_BBB** is required for the form to be submitted.  There is an oppurtunity for the user to submit up to 5 **s_AAA/s_BBB** combos.  Think of this as a form where you can refer up to five friends, but must at least submit 1 for the form to submit.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">      
     (function ($, W, D) {
         var SIGNUPVALIDATION = {};

         SIGNUPVALIDATION.UTIL = {
             setupFormValidation: function () {
                 //form validation rules
                 $("#friend_req").validate({
                     rules: {
                         s_referee_email: "required",
                         s_referee_fname: "required", 

                     },
                     messages: {
                         s_referee_email: "Please enter at least one friend's email address",
                         s_referee_fname: "Please enter your friends first name",
                     },
                     submitHandler: function (form) {
                         form.submit();
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
         //when the DOM has loaded setup form validation rules
         $(D).ready(function ($) {
             SIGNUPVALIDATION.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
         });

     })(jQuery, window, document);
  </script>
```

Comment: Please add the tag for, or update your question with, the validation library you are using.

Comment: Added, thanks for the advice Mike!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are specifically looking to do it in javascript then you can just add `required` to an HTML5 form. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

The problem then becomes Safari - which will not submit the form if the required fields are left blank- but will also NOT render the error to the user. Your user will be sitting there not knowing why the form will not submit. In which case you can use some JS to do that. You may ask why not just do it in JS then and skip the HTML validation? Well, I suppose that's a personal decision, but I like to use a combo approach just because I like the little popovers that the HTML validation gives you in the other browsers.

If you are going to do it in JS you are going to create a function that grabs the inputs you want to validate like so:

```
nameInput   = document.querySelector("#name").value
```

And from there you can check if there is a length to the input if you want to make sure it meets a certain minimum of characters or you can just check to see if it has a value using `.test()` with something like:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+/.test(nameInput)
```

From there, if it does, you proceed to submit, and if not, then you issue an error to the user:

```
*assuming you have a div with a class of "error", if not you could create one dynamically

else {
  error.innerHTML = "You must provide a name.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Moly.  Using the HTML5 solution is a nice elegant solution!  Thank you! not to get the ajax running...

Comment: your welcome! if this solved your problem, then do consider marking it as the solution ;)

Comment: sorry im new this stack, marked as solution. Thakns HolyMoly.